# Symbol file /home/symphony/mono/mcs/class/System.Web/test/bin/Debug/System.Web.dll.mdb doesn't match image

Tags: mono, monodevelop, system.web

When I build the `System.Web-net_4_0.sln`, (Ubuntu12.04, monoDevelop), result is build successful, then I try to debug the `System.web.dll` using the Test console application:

```
        public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        System.Web.UI.Page page=new System.Web.UI.Page();\\**Make a breakpoint here**
        page.ProcessRequest(null);
    }
```

the result is :

```
Symbol file /home/symphony/mono/mcs/class/System.Web/test/bin/Debug/System.Web.dll.mdb doesn't match image /home/symphony/mono/mcs/class/System.Web/test/bin/Debug/System.Web.dll
```

any body can help me?

Answer (score 0):

After building the sln, did you run "sudo make install" (with the shell, in the mcs/class/System.Web/ folder) so the new DLL gets into your GAC and all?

Also, it may be better to build the assembly via "make" instead of building the SLN file. I don't think the build system is using the SLN files for building, they are just there so it is easier for you to hack the Mono sources within an IDE.

Comment: I had try that. My purpose is to step into the Framework code(Specifically System.Web.Dll), all assembly work normal ,but when I try with System.web.dll ,it doesn't work？ there is some special restrictions in System.web.dll?

Comment: Did you uncheck the MonoDevelop option Edit->Options->Preferences->Debugger->Debug project code only; do not step into framework code?

Comment: yes, I do.I supsect  option Build ->Compiler->General Options ->Define Symbols DEBUG;TRACE;NET_1_1;NET_2_0;NET_3_0;NET_3_5;NET_4_0;INSIDE_SYSTEM_WEB;WEBSERVICES_DEP;MONOWEB_DEP;SYSTEMCORE_DEP, means somethings? do this can provide you valuable information ?(I am from china,thank you for the responses)